# Why does creating a view in VS ASP .NET Core projects results in installing SQL package via NUGET

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

When I'm creating an empty partial view this window pops out:

[Nuget installing staff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZLei.png)

Which result in 3 new package installed i've never needed

Why does it do that?

Comment: Documentation is [very clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.1) about that

Answer (score 0):

Check in .csproj file if those three packages are present or not.

If these are present, then the scaffolding process will do nuget package restore and try to install those package.

Comment: Nothing is present there